# What happens to the thermal energy during thermionic emission?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

If a particle tunnels through a potential barrier, the particle's energy is equal to its energy before tunneling. So what happens during thermionic emission? Is the energy given to the electrons through heating given back to the metal? Or does it perhaps get converted into kinetic energy in the electrons?

What happens to the energy supplied to the electrons through heating in thermionic emission?

Answer (score 0):

In a hot metal, the electrons are at the same temperature as the lattice. The thermal energy is the random kinetic energy of the metal ions and the electrons. The (small) fraction of electrons in the metal with sufficient thermal energy to surmount the metal surface potential barrier can be emitted. This is called thermionic emission.The emitted electrons just carry away the energy they had inside the metal before emission.

Comment: So they take away the thermal energy that is supplied too? and in what form? Kinetic energy?